# Parse JSON-like markup in perl

Tags: json, perl, parsing, markup, steam-web-api

I am not sure what markup this is to be honest, I though at first JSON but using `parse_json` from `JSON::Parse` fails with: `JSON error at line 2, byte 15/1380740: Unexpected character '{' parsing initial state: expecting whitespace: '\n', '\r', '\t', ' ' at ....`

This is what I parse into an hash: https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/apps/730/scripts/items/items_game.d8a302f03758b99ab65b60b3a4a11d73ca4738bd.txt.

What I tried:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use JSON::Parse 'parse_json';

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $response = $ua->get( "https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/apps/730/scripts/items/items_game.d8a302f03758b99ab65b60b3a4a11d73ca4738bd.txt" );
if ( $response->is_success ) {
     my $game_items = parse_json( $response->content );
     # ... do stuff
}
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is this JSON or must I create some hack-ish solution to parse this?

I could not find any suggestions through the "Questions that may already have your answer" section though I think it would be easier if I knew the name of this markup.

Comment: It looks like JSON without the separators! As far as I can see it's all hashes -- there don't appear to be any arrays. Should be easy to parse recursively

Comment: If you read the [Steam Web API documentation](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_Web_API) you will see that what you have here is *VDF* or *Valve Data Format*, and you can get your data in JSON format (or XML) by adding `format=json` to the query parameters of the URL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will process your data, It's a bit hacky but it does the job!

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

use Data::Dump;
use LWP::Simple qw/ mirror /;

use constant URL    => 'https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/apps/730/scripts/items/items_game.d8a302f03758b99ab65b60b3a4a11d73ca4738bd.txt';
use constant MIRROR => 'steamcdn.txt';

my $data = do {
    mirror URL, MIRROR;
    open my $fh, '<', MIRROR;
    local $/;
    <$fh>;
};

my ($hash, $key);
my @stack;

while ( ) {

    if ( $data =~ / \G \s* " ([^"]*) " /gcx ) {
        if ( defined $key ) {
            $hash->{$key} = $1;
            $key = undef;
        }
        else {
            $key = $1;
        }
    }
    elsif ( $data =~ / \G \s* \{ /gcx ) {
        push @stack, [ $hash, $key ];
        $key = $hash = undef;
    }
    elsif ( $data =~ / \G \s* \} /gcx ) {
        die "Structure unbalanced" if defined $key or @stack == 0;
        my ($parent, $key) = @{ pop @stack };
        $parent->{$key} = $hash;
        $hash = $parent;

    }
    else {
        last;
    }
}

die "Structure unbalanced" if @stack;

dd $hash;
```

#### output

```
{
  items_game => {
    alternate_icons2        => {
                                 weapon_icons => {
                                   65604    => {
                                                 icon_path => "econ/default_generated/weapon_deagle_hy_ddpat_urb_light",
                                               },
                                   65605    => {
                                                 icon_path => "econ/default_generated/weapon_deagle_hy_ddpat_urb_medium",
                                               },
                                   65606    => {
                                                 icon_path => "econ/default_generated/weapon_deagle_hy_ddpat_urb_heavy",
                                               },
                                   65684    => {
                                                 icon_path => "econ/default_generated/weapon_deagle_aa_flames_light",
                                               },
                                   65685    => {
                                                 icon_path => "econ/default_generated/weapon_deagle_aa_flames_medium",
                                               },
                                   65686    => {
                                                 icon_path => "econ/default_generated/weapon_deagle_aa_flames_heavy",
                                               },
                                   65696    => {
                                                 icon_path => "econ/default_generated/weapon_deagle_so_night_light",
                                               },
                                   65697    => {
                                                 icon_path => "econ/default_generated/weapon_deagle_so_night_medium",
                                               },
                                   65698    => {
                                                 icon_path => "econ/default_generated/weapon_deagle_so_night_heavy",
                                               },
                                   65780    => {
                                                 icon_path => "econ/default_generated/weapon_deagle_aa_vertigo_light",
                                               },
                                   65781    => {
                                                 icon_path => "econ/default_generated/weapon_deagle_aa_vertigo_medium",
                                               },
                                   65782    => {
                                                 icon_path => "econ/default_generated/weapon_deagle_aa_vertigo_heavy",
                                               },
                                   65896    => {
                                                 icon_path => "econ/default_generated/weapon_deagle_hy_mottled_sand_light",
                                               },
                                   65897    => {
                                                 icon_path => "econ/default_generated/weapon_deagle_hy_mottled_sand_medium",
                                               },
                                   65898    => {
                                                 icon_path => "econ/default_generated/weapon_deagle_hy_mottled_sand_heavy",
                                               },
                                   66276    => {
                                                 icon_path => "econ/default_generated/weapon_deagle_am_scales_bravo_light",
                                               },
                                   66277    => {
                                                 icon_path => "econ/default_generated/weapon_deagle_am_scales_bravo_medium",
                                               },
                                   66278    => {
```

Comment: Hacky indeed, I though it would be a much simpler task, I guess not!

Comment: As parsing goes, that's pretty trivial. There are only three possible tokens: a string, an opening brace, and a closing brace. My program just checks which of those comes next and handles each case in two or three lines of code. I used a separate stack array to eliminate the recursion caused by the nested hashes

Comment: It is much simpler if you just request XML or JSON in the first place as mentioned in the comments.

Comment: You can handle the whitespace in one place using `$data =~ / \G \s+ /xgc` instead of handling it in front of every token.

Answer (score 2):

```
my $file = do { local $/; <> };

my @stack = [];
my %handlers = (
   '"' => sub {
      /\G ([^"]*) " /xgc
         or die("Unterminated \"\n");
      push(@{ $stack[-1] }, $1);
   },
   '{' => sub {
      die("Expected string\n") if @{ $stack[-1] } % 2 == 0;
      push(@stack, []);
   },
   '}' => sub {
      die("Unmatched \"}\"\n") if @stack == 1;
      my $hash = pop(@stack);
      die("Missing value\n") if @$hash % 2 == 1;
      push(@{ $stack[-1] }, { @$hash });
   },
);

my $data;
for ($file) {
   while (1) {
      my $next_char = /\G \s* (\S) /gcx ? $1 : last;
      my $handler = $handlers{$next_char}
         or die("Unrecognized character \"$next_char\"\n");
      $handler->();
   }

   die("Unmatched \"{\"\n") if @stack > 1;
   my $hash = pop(@stack);
   die("Missing value\n") if @$hash % 2 == 1;
   $data = { @$hash };
}
```

Aside from a simpler stack than Borodin's and the use of a dispatch table instead of a long sequence of "if", this version provides proper error detection. This will detect truncated documents as well as unsupported features.

Comment: Hi @ikegami, do you have a working example of this code with my example? I have an issue with Borodin's example now with a similar file, my guess is a unsupported feature.

Comment: There was a small error. Fixed. Now works with the example in the Question.